# Trading post not showing

Tags: kittens-game

I have unlocked the Currency technology, and this successfully unlocked the Gold Ore upgrade in workshop, but I can't see the button to build Trading Post in the buildings tab, as indicated by the wiki.

Anyone else experiencing this (firefox) and/or knows whats the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fixed itself.

Apparently doesn't always show up for a while. May also be due to not having built any gold yet, which is a required resource for Tradepost

Comment: Occasionally it can also be that you need to switch screens. I.E. go to village and back to bonfire

Comment: Generally, you need about 30% of all required resources before a new building shows up - so you need to stock up some gold first.